# Google Cloud Endpoint Authentication from my Android Client: Audience not Allowed and Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-endpoints, service-object

I'm trying to access a deployed appengine backend api using OAuth2.0 support from my android client.

Authentication is working fine from the api explorer using the authorised email address

On the android side, I'm using the credentials/account picker method described here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android

But I get a 403 status code saying the access is forbidden  and the following in the appengine log when accessing from an android client:

```
D 12:52:53.042 Checking for id_token.
W 12:52:53.046 Audience not allowed: 901326459160-vnpoik6ebefbnhtagqns7r0qlkt31gdo.apps.googleusercontent.com
D 12:52:53.047 Checking for oauth token.
D 12:52:53.049 Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user.
I 12:52:53.050 Access rejected from none user.
```

What is happeing because the web app client id has been included in the whitelist for client ids and also the android client id?....

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems that the your application is passing the incorrect user token or to the backend API, that's why it is showing that "Oauth framework user didn't match Oauth token user. I will suggest you to check the clientID you use in your code for "Configuring Your Android client to provide credentials"  on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android) and see if the client ID (Android) is same as in the developer console

Answer (score 0):

I figured what was wrong.... The web client email was passed as the audience in the endpoint Api method instead of the web client id